# I need help understanding how calling functions works

Tags: python, function

```
def exact_change(user_total):
    num_quarters = user_total // 25 
    user_total %= 25 
    num_dimes = user_total // 10 
    user_total %= 10
    num_nickels = user_total // 5 
    user_total %= 5 
    num_pennies = user_total
    return(num_pennies, num_nickels, num_dimes, num_quarters)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_val = int(input()) 
    num_pennies, num_nickels, num_dimes, num_quarters = exact_change(input_val)
  
    if input_val <= 0: 
        print('no change')     
    else:
        if num_pennies > 1: 
            print(f'{num_pennies} pennies') 
        elif num_pennies ==1: 
            print(f'{num_pennies} penny')
            
        if num_nickels > 1: 
            print(f'{num_nickels} nickels') 
        elif num_nickels == 1: 
            print(f'{num_nickels} nickel')
            
        if num_dimes > 1:
            print(f'{num_dimes} dimes') 
        elif num_dimes == 1: 
            print(f'{num_dimes} dime') 
            
        if num_quarters > 1: 
            print(f'{num_quarters} quarters') 
        elif num_quarters == 1: 
            print(f'{num_quarters} quarter')
```

I'm struggling to understand why we need this  `num_pennies, num_nickels, num_dimes, num_quarters = exact_change(input_val)` line of code because if the function already returns those values why would we need to initialize those in our main function.. and couldnt we just make the variables global inside exact_change() function instead of calling them manually in the main functions?

Comment: modifying global variables in a function is often a bad idea. It is good design to create local variables, and return the result.

Comment: Whether or not your function returns variables, changes globals, or changes instance variables of a class - it's all up to you, how you want the program to work, and how you want it to be designed. A program can use any of those options and still be functionally identical.

Comment: Scope (or variable scope) is what you're looking for. See [understanding Python scope](https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/).

Answer (score 0):

All the variable that are created inside a function, exist only inside a function while the function it's executing the code. They they get disposed to free memory for other uses.

In order to use what the function return (if it's not a void function) you have to store it to a variable.

In this case the funtion return multiple value, so you unpack them into 4 diffrent one for better use, if you would store all of them in a single one it will be a tuple.

You could to the variables global, but the idea of a function it's to reuse part of the code multiple times. So if you do the variable global they will likly exist only once.